# Laravel 4: CodeSleeve asset-pipeline, specify which path is assigned to which route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, asset-pipeline

What I'd like to know is if it's possible to assign a specific path of the asset-pipeline to a specific route.

For example, I want

```php
'paths' => array(
    'app/assets/images/dogs',
    'lib/assets/images/dogs',
    'provider/assets/images/dogs'
),
```

routed to

> http://application.com/assets/dogs

instead of

> http://application.com/assets

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried out of curiosity making a folder inside **provider/assets/images** and moving a picture in there, and the route changed automatically.

I didn't think it would have been that easy... well I was wrong.